# Can I use sorcery points to regain a spell slot to cast Counterspell?

Tags: dnd-5e, sorcerer

If my Sorcerer has used up all of her level 3 spell slots, but wants to use a reaction to cast Counterspell, can she use 5 sorcery points during a reaction to regain a level 3 spell slot to cast the Counterspell?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No.

Creating a spell slot is a bonus action and thus has to be done on your turn.

> *Creating Spell Slots.* You can transform unexpended sorcery points into one spell slot **as a bonus action on your turn.** The Creating Spell Slots table shows the cost of creating a spell slot of a given level. You can create spell slots no higher in level than 5th. (PHB 101)